# iOS: Cannot debug UIWebView after another UIWebView is loaded

Tags: ios, uiwebview, hybrid-mobile-app, javascriptcore

I have got an application with multiple UIWebViews. I have one UIWebView holding all business logics and other UIWebViews for displaying purpose. However,I found that the breakpoint doesn't stop if the UIWebView is not the last one loaded.

Could someone help me with it?

ps: I use safari's develop tool to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Using this [test project](https://github.com/drichardson/MultiUIWebView) and Safari I was able to confirm that it is possible to debug multiple `UIWebViews` in iOS simulator. See [demo video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUYCBHjA_7Y).

I also verified that you can still debug a `UIWebView` when its `hidden` flag is set to `YES`.

I was able to place breakpoints on both `UIWebViews`. When I pressed `Command+R` to in Safari debugger the pages were refreshed and the breakpoints hit as expected.

Note, however, that when you kill the iOS app in Xcode, you lose your Safari debug session as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The issue I had was caused by javascript mapping, and it seems no way to disable it in safari debugger. I accept this as answer.